# Is it possible to summarize the Interpreter initialization steps?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Problem:
The extension calls the Interpreter several times on Interpreter selection to retrieve some information like:

> *Interpreter.exe -c "import sys;print(sys.prefix)"
>
>   Interpreter.exe -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
>
>   Interpreter.exe -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
>
>   Interpreter.exe -m site –user-site
>
>   Interpreter.exe -m pylint --disable=all --enable=F,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,unused-wildcard-import,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open……….
>
>   Interpreter.exe d:\python-vscode\vscode-python\pythonFiles\interpreterInfo.py*

We have our own IronPython 2.7.x based Interpreter that loads additional Objects + Runtime, which takes some seconds. Each process needs exclusive access to some objects until the runtime is loaded and we can´t change this because this is an external dependency. Waiting until the resources are availabe is slowing down the initialization as well. Is it possible to combine the steps mentioned above in one call or to optimize this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to optimize those into a single call would be to send a pull request to the Python extension itself at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python to change it to aggregate the calls somehow.

Comment: Good idea! Thank you very much!